# Is it possible to disable the “implementing deprecated class” warning?

Tags: xcode, clang

I have an iOS project that uses CocoaPods for dependency management. One of the pods I use implements a certain class that is marked as deprecated. This produces a warning:

> Implementing deprecated class

Is there a compiler flag or something that will let me suppress this warning? If it matters, the class is both declared and implemented in Objective-C files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Podfile, add the `inhibit_warnings` flag:

```
pod 'ThePod', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

where `ThePod` is the name of the pod that is throwing the warning. Then run `pod install` to update your project.